# paired T test alternative for non normal data in sas?

Tags: sas

I have 2 variables on which I want to perform paired t test. one has skewness of 9 and the other is a normal distribution. This is a survey data so unfortunately I wont be able to do a transformation on the var with 9 skewness. i am using SAS

I need to test if price is more important for the customer or is reliability more important to the customer

What are my alternatives to t paired test? I believe paired t test needs normal data.

thanks

Comment: Your question is more stats oriented and thus more suited to the Cross Validated community (http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Good luck! (You'll probably find that with a large enough sample, skewness is not an issue, as per the Central Limit Theorem).

Comment: This distribution of the mean needs to be normal not the distribution itself. But you should ask on Cross Validated not here.

Answer (score 0):

`proc npar1way` provides non-parametric statistical tests that you can use for non-normal data. For the two groups, ensure that it's a flat file, as you will want to use the `class` statement to do the test.

For example:

```
data have;
input customer value;
datalines;
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 150
1 90
2 500
2 600
2 700
2 2000
2 1500
;
run;

proc npar1way data=have;
    class customer;
    var value;
run;
```